# sql SUM value incorrect when using joins and group by

Tags: sql

Im writing a query that sums order values broken down by product groups - problem is that when I add joins the aggregated SUM gets greatly inflated - I assume its because its adding in duplicate rows. Im kinda new to SQL, but I think its because I need to construct the query with sub selects or nested joins?

All data returns as expected, and my joins pull out the needed data, but the SUM(inv.item_total) AS Value returned is much higher that it should be - SQL below

```
SELECT  so.Company_id, SUM(inv.item_total) AS Value, co.company_name,
agents.short_desc, stock_type.short_desc AS Type


FROM SORDER as so

JOIN company AS co ON co.company_id = so.company_id
JOIN invoice AS inv ON inv.Sorder_id = so.Sorder_id
JOIN sorder_item AS soitem ON soitem.sorder_id = so.Sorder_id
JOIN STOCK AS stock ON stock.stock_id = soitem.stock_id
JOIN stock_type AS stock_type ON stock_type.stype_id = stock.stype_id
JOIN AGENTS AS AGENTS ON agents.agent_id = co.agent_id

WHERE
 co.last_ordered >'01-JAN-2012' and so.Sotype_id='1'


GROUP BY so.Company_id,co.company_name,agents.short_desc, stock_type.short_desc
```

Any guidence on how I should structure this query to pull out an "un-duplicated" SUM(inv.item_total) AS Value much appreciated.

Comment: I assume one Invoice can have many order items, and that that alone is the cause of your duplication/inflation? Or are there other 1:many relationships on your joins?

Comment: I just noticed, between invoice and agents you have 3 tables being joined in.  But you never use them for anything, is that just because you simplified things for us, or could you just remove those three joins?

Answer (score 0):

To get an accurate sum, you want only the joins that are needed.  So, this version should work:

```
SELECT so.Company_id, SUM(inv.item_total) AS Value, co.company_name
FROM SORDER so JOIN
     company co
     ON co.company_id = so.company_id JOIN
     invoice inv
     ON inv.Sorder_id = so.Sorder_id
group by so.Company_id, co.company_name
```

You can then add in one join at a time to see where the multiplication is taking place.  I'm guessing it has to do with the agents.

Comment: Hi, the SUM duplicates are appearing when the join: `JOIN STOCK AS stock ON stock.stock_id = soitem.stock_id` is added. But, problem is the join is needed to get the stock type description! I can't see a way of joining but not causing the duplicates in the SUM?

Comment: You need to think better about what each column means in the resulting table.  The sum of inventory is at the company level.  But what is the stock level?  Does a company only have one stock?  If not, how do you partition the invoices?

Comment: Each sales order has multiple sales order items (description, item code etc.) to represent the order - they are stored in the sorder_items table - so each sorder_items row is linked back via the sorder_id. But I need to grab the item group from that table. Not sure its possible to pull out without an inflated SUM - my SQL skills not quite there yet!

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like the joins are not accurate.

**First suspect join**

For example, would an agent be per `company`, or per `invoice`?

If it is per order, then should the join be something along the lines of

`JOIN AGENTS AS AGENTS ON agents.agent_id = inv.agent_id`

**Second suspect join**

Can one `order` have many `items`, and many `invoices` at the same time?  That can cause problems as well. Say an order has 3 items and 3 invoices were sent out.  According to your joins, the same item will show up 3 times means a total of 9 line items where there should be only 3.  You may need to eliminate the `invoices` table

**Possible way to solve this on your own:**

I would remove all the grouping and sums, and see if you can filter by one invoice produce an unique set of rows for all the data.

Start with an invoice that has just one item and inspect your result set for accuracy.  If that works, then add another invoice that has multiple and check the rows to see if you get your perfect dataset back.  If not, then the columns that have repeating values (Company Name, Item Name, Agent Name, etc) are usually a good starting point for checking up on why the duplicates are showing up.